# How to make a flow run if Opportunity Closed Date equals Today

Tags: workflow, opportunity, visual-workflow

I have a flow created in Salesforce (using Cloud Flow Designer).  This flow essentially duplicates an opportunity but changes a few fields - in other words, it creates a renewal opportunity.  I currently have it run by pressing a custom button.  However, I would like it to automatically run every time an opportunity's close date is equal to TODAY.

I have searched Google, but can't find a good answer.  I am pretty new to Salesforce, so it could be something simple that I am missing.  I am using the developer edition.

Thanks!

Comment: Currently you can call the flow from a trigger or ask to have the process builder turned on via a salesforce case. Take a look at this blog, https://salesforcewizard.wordpress.com/tag/headless-flow/, for more details.

Comment: I have created a workflow rule that has met specific criteria (a custom field is greater than or equal to 1 AND Stage equals "Closed Won").  I am trying to create a time-dependent workflow action to fire the flow one hour after the close date.  I do have flow triggers enabled on my account, but I only see that option come up under immediate workflow actions.  Any suggestions?  I don't necessarily have to use flow triggers but thought that would be the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the process builder, you should be able to open a case with SalesForce and ask them to turn on the Process Builder. I had it turned on in our org and just put together a quick process similar to what you are trying to do. Here's a screenshot: [image]

1. Choose Object and Specify When to Start the Process (Opportunity)
2. Define Criteria for this Action Group (Select your criteria above)
3. Do you want to execute the actions only if the record was created or edited to meet criteria?*(Yes)
4. Click on the "Scheduled Actions" box and set to 1 Hour from now.
5. Click on the "Add an action" in the "Scheduled Actions" box
6. Select "Create a Record", give it a name and select the object type
7. Select the fields you want to prepopulate, click the pencil icon to change it to a field value and select your opportunity fields you want to copy over.
8. Activate